# show loading gif while html loads with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, loader

I want to show a loading image while the html I load in with Ajax is loading,  the following code doesn't seem to work.

```
$('#loading-image').bind('ajaxStart', function(){
          $(this).show();
    }).bind('ajaxStop', function(){
          $(this).hide();
        });
```

I want the loading image to appear  when loading in the content of game.html to the .content element.

```
$('body').on('click', '.mch-ajax', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#mch-overlay').fadeOut(300);
        $( ".content" ).load("game.html", function() {
                $( ".note" ).delay(400).fadeIn(700);
                $( ".route" ).delay(800).fadeIn(700);
                $( ".start-btn" ).delay(1200).fadeIn(700);
        }); 
    });
```

When you click on "play", then the button "start the game" executes the following code:

```
$( ".content" ).load("game.html"....
```

the HTML and css:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to the [upgrade guide for jquery 1.9.0.](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/)

> AJAX events should be attached to document
>
> As of jQuery 1.9, the global AJAX events (ajaxStart, ajaxStop,
>   ajaxSend, ajaxComplete, ajaxError, and ajaxSuccess) are only triggered
>   on the document element. Change the program to listen for the AJAX
>   events on the document. For example, if the code currently looks like
>   this:
>
> $("#status").ajaxStart(function(){ $(this).text("Ajax started"); });
>
> Change it to this:
>
> $(document).ajaxStart(function(){ $("#status").text("Ajax started");
>   });

Comment: thanks, but how would I amend my code for this, It's not very clear.

Comment: f.e. 
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
          $('#loading-image').show(); });

Answer (score 2):

Try using `beforeSend` and `complete` in `$.ajaxSetup`

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('#loading-image').show();
    },
    complete: function(){
        $('#loading-image').hide();
    }
});
```